# How to enable activex controls in ie using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, activex

Is it there any way to enable activex controls of internet explorer through javascript ,I searched internet cant find any trusted resources , is it possible to enable activex controls through javascript

The only source which i got can be found [here](http://mar.anomy.net/entry/2006/11/24/02.12.18/)

Thanks In advance

Comment: You can't change the browsers's settings like this with Javascript. If the user disabled it, it's disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to activate them via JavaScipt or anything like that. I think it used to be a security measure, but I'm not sure.

If you look at MSDN however there is a solution:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537508(v=vs.85).aspx
If you dynamicaly add controls through JavaScript after the DOM is loaded they get activated right away.

Comment: "To automatically activate ActiveX controls, Internet Explorer must be using versions of vbscript.dll and jscript.dll newer than September 30, 2003."

Answer (score 1):

Enabling ActiveX through javascript is not possible.  This is a browser level setting.

Comment: i have enclosed an link,please review it ,i am confused now